# If only the identity matrix and zero matrix is in a set. Is it a subspace of all 2 x 2 matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

So my question is if I only have the identity matrix and zero matrix in a set, that are both 2 x 2 matrices, is it a subspace of all matrices that are 2 x 2?

Comment: Under what operation and over what ring or field?

Comment: No, it isn't, unless you are working over the field $\mathbb{F_2}$.

Comment: but just having the zero matrix, then it would be a subspace, correct?

Comment: Yes, the zero vector alone is always a subspace. The trivial subspace.

Comment: can you explain why the set in the question is not a subspace. Is it because it is not closed under scalar multiplication?

Comment: It is not closed under addition either.  $I+I$ is not equal to the zero matrix nor the identity matrix (*again, unless working over the field $\Bbb F_2$, but if you don't specify the scalar field it is usually assumed you mean for the scalar field to be the reals*)